# Algorithms package ignores caption package

Tags: captions, algorithms, incompatibility

I'm using the `algorithms` package in my document to get a floating environment for algorithms to live in.

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
```

I'm using the `caption` package to make the captions on my figures smaller.

```
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,bf]{caption}
```

The `algorithms` package ignores the `caption` package.

Is there any way to make it respond to `caption`'s options?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `\captionsetup` with `algorithm` option; since a comment suggest that you only want to have the label boldfaced and both label and text in `\footnotesize` size, it's enough to say:

```
\captionsetup[algorithm]{font=footnotesize}
```

since, by default, the label for algorithm captions is boldfaced.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup[algorithm]{font=footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Euclid's algorithm}\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
\State $a\gets b$
\State $b\gets r$
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
\State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It may be useful to note that `\floatname{algorithm}{\footnotesize Algorithm}` controls the caption's label independent of its text.

Comment: @Richard: to control the label and the text separately, you can use the `labelfont` and `textfont` keys (or a combination of `font` and the other two). In your concrete example, it's enough to use `\captionsetup[algorithm]{font={footnotesize}}`, since by default the label will be boldfaced.

Comment: As an alternative to the solution above, one could redefine the caption style `ruled`. See caption package doc., section about interaction with the `float` package.

Answer (score 0):

algorithm2e provides its own "do not float" [H] float specifier, setting the contents in a minipage if used this way. So one would have to use

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
% <your algorithm here>
\end{algorithm}
```

under those conditions. A large amount of leg-work is done by the package at the start of the algorithm environment in order to set things up since it has its own interface (using \; to denote line-ends, otherwise known as a horizontal space in math-mode outside the environment).