# Caption spacing using algorithm2e

Tags: spacing, captions, algorithm2e

I am trying to add some spacing above/below captions of algorithms using the algorithm2e package.
Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,boxed]{algorithm2e}

\SetKwInput{KwInput}{Input}
\SetKwInput{KwOutput}{Output}

\begin{document}

  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \SetAlgoLined
    \KwInput{Parameters...}

    \KwOutput{$\emptyset$}

    \If{Condition}
    {
      Do something \;
    }
    \caption{Algoritm test...}
  \end{algorithm}

  \blindtext{}

  \begin{figure}[!h]
    \caption{Figure test...}
  \end{figure}

  \blindtext{}

\end{document}
```

You can see that the caption is squeezed in below the box containing the algorithm. There is no space separating the box from the caption and not enough space separating the caption from the following text. I would like to add the same amount of space above and below the caption, but I have not yet figured out how to do that: There seems to be a working solution for the algorithms package (see [Algorithms package ignores caption package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57117/algorithms-package-ignores-caption-package)) , but I can't figure out how to make a `\captionsetup` apply to an algorithm2e caption. Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To use the command `\captionsetup` you must have loaded the `caption` package...

Anyway, this can be done without it.

First of all, the spacing between the caption and the rest of the text is null because you are preventing the `algorithm` to float using `H` as a position specifier. Use `h` instead, which means "place it here" but keeps the `algorithm` a floating object (the same as `h` for `figure`s and `table`s).

Then you can adjust the spacing between the body of the `algorithm` and its caption through the command `\SetAlCapSkip`.

In other words, substituting the line

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
```

with

```
\begin{algorithm}[h]
```

and inserting

```
\SetAlCapSkip{1em}
```

in the preamble (adjust `1em` to your needs) should be what you want.

---

Complete MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,boxed]{algorithm2e}

\SetAlCapSkip{1em}

\SetKwInput{KwInput}{Input}
\SetKwInput{KwOutput}{Output}

\begin{document}

  \begin{algorithm}[h]
    \SetAlgoLined
    \KwInput{Parameters...}

    \KwOutput{$\emptyset$}

    \If{Condition}
    {
      Do something \;
    }
    \caption{Algoritm test...}
  \end{algorithm}

  \blindtext{}

  \begin{figure}[!h]
    \caption{Figure test...}
  \end{figure}

  \blindtext{}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]